# How would one go about making .resizeable() conditional?

Tags: swiftui, state

I have a state `@State var showImage = false` and I want my image modifier `.resizable()` only to be enabled on false.

```
struct URLImageView: View {
    @State var showImage = false

    var body: some View {
        if urlImageModel.image != nil {
                Image(Image("Foo.png"))
                .resizable() /shrug
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: showImage ? 350 : 150, height: showImage ? 350 : 150)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous))
                .onTapGesture{
                    self.showImage.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating an `extension` on `Image` that conditionally applies `resizable`:

```
extension Image {
    @ViewBuilder
    func conditionalResizable(_ resizable: Bool) -> some View {
        if resizable {
            self.resizable()
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

Then replace:

```
.resizable()
```

with:

```
.conditionalResizable(!showImage)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Image {
    func isResizable(_ condition: Bool) -> Image {
        switch condition {
        case true:
            return
                self
                .resizable()
        case false:
            return
                self
        }
    }
}

struct SomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "mustache")
                .isResizable(true)
            Image(systemName: "mustache.fill")
                .isResizable(false)
        }
    }
}
```

**@State** must be private – for any case.